# How to automate "do not disturb"?

Tags: notifications, automation, do-not-disturb

How can I trigger "do not disturb" at regular intervals, say during lectures on MWF from 10am to 11am?

In Yosemite (and Mavericks) one clicks on the notifications icon, then swipes down to reveal the "do not disturb" switch. I'm wondering if it's possible to automate turning the switch to on/off at regular intervals.

Answer (score 3):

Go on Settings -> Notifications

[image]

Comment: Interesting.. thanks.. but "When mirroring to TVs and projectors" is already checked, and yet I do receive notifications with DisplayPort connected to a projector.

Comment: Strange.. Perhaps you have to make a feedback to Apple ;)

Comment: @Calaf, are you sure that you "mirror" your display? Or do you set it as a second monitor as is common?

Comment: By the way, you can also just option click the menu icon to toggle it on/off (instead of opening the panel and swiping down).